# Regex to remove '%i' and similar from string in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I have a web app which needs to parse string files from iOS apps. I am trying to find all instances of Objective-C-style percent escapes in a string, and add a span class to them, in PHP. For instance,

```
"Hello my name is %@ and I have %ld cats"
```

Should become:

```
"Hello my name is <span class='b'>%@</span> and I have <span class='b'>%ld</span> cats"
```

Unfortunately my regex skills are beyond rusty. How can I do this correctly and efficiently? (will potentially be parsing 1000+ strings at a time)

Comment: Don't have the time to write you a regex at the moment (I'd have to dredge up the memories myself just like you) but a FANTASTIC TOOL for getting your regexes right can be found here:
http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe...

```
$string = "Hello my name is %@ and I have %ld cats";
$pattern = "/(%[^\s]+)/";
$replacedStr = preg_replace($pattern, "<span class='b'>$1</span>", $string);
```

Per NullUserException, this will also work (and is actually shorter!):

```
$string = "Hello my name is %@ and I have %ld cats";
$pattern = "/%\S+/";
$replacedStr = preg_replace($pattern, "<span class='b'>$0</span>", $string);
```

Comment: `[^\s]` can be written as `\S`; you can also drop the capture group and use `$0`